# Map two pandas dataframe and add a column to the first dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have posted two sample dataframes. I would like to map one column of a dataframe with respect to the index of a column in another dataframe and place the values back to the first dataframe shown as below

```
A = np.array([0,1,1,3,5,2,5,4,2,0])
B = np.array([55,75,86,98,100,111])
    
df1 = pd.Series(A, name='data').to_frame()
df2 = pd.Series(B, name='values_for_replacement').to_frame()
```

The below is the first dataframe df1

```
   data
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     3
4     5
5     2
6     5
7     4
8     2
9     0
```

And the below is the second dataframe df2

```
   values_for_replacement
0                      55
1                      75
2                      86
3                      98
4                     100
5                     111
```

**The below is the output needed** (Mapped with respect to the index of the df2)

```
   data  new_data
0     0        55
1     1        75
2     1        75
3     3        98
4     5       111
5     2        86
6     5       111
7     4       100
8     2        86
9     0        55
```

*I would kindly like to know how one can achieve this using some pandas functions like map.*

Looking forward for some answers. Many thanks in advance

Comment: ``df1.data.map(df2.values_for_replacement)`` ?

Comment: Woww ... This perfectly works .. Thanks